# Memory Allocating (malloc) a Struct Array

Tags: c, struct, malloc

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
struct CELL {
    char* data;
    struct CELL* next;
} ;

struct CELL* table;

// The line below gives an error
table = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(struct HASHCELL));
```

I am trying to create an array of struct CELL using malloc.

However, doing so gives "warning: type specifier missing, defaults to 'int' [-Wimplicit-int]". Consequently, it gives "error: redefinition of 'table' with a different type: 'int' vs 'struct CELL * ". I am new to C and I am unsure why this is happening.

Comment: Why not do `static struct CELL table[100]` *if you don't need malloc*

Comment: Is it legal to define a member of a struct as being itself while defining the struct ?

Comment: What compiler are you using?

Comment: @EricPostpischil why ? shouldn't `stdlib` be enough ?

Comment: @An Ant I have tried not using malloc. But for some reason, when I run my program, I either get a segmentation error or a bus error. I assumed those two errors happened because I did not allocate memory. However, I am not sure as I am new to the language.

Comment: @AnAnt: `stdlib.h` has nothing to do with the redefinition of the user-defined `table`.

Comment: @Vahan I am compiling my code on Visual Studio Code.

Comment: @EricPostpischil I see, i though only malloc needed a library header there

Comment: @AnAnt: The source codecshown does not contain any definition of a structure inside itself. A pointer to a structure is not the structure and may be a member of the structure.

Comment: @EricPostpischil isn't `struct CELL {
    char *data;
    struct CELL* next;
}` the definition ?

Comment: @AnAnt: So, what about it?

Comment: @EricPostpischil Ah, so are you sying what I was thinking ? that this sort of code confuses the compiler ?

Comment: @AnAnt: No, it is fine. Why do you think there is any problem with it?

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve]. I tried [this code](https://www.godbolt.org/z/bMsP7r) and it compiles fine.

Comment: @EricPostpischil Because I honestly have no idea how you can define something as a member of itself ... how would that work in the compiler ?

Comment: @Jabberwocky That is pretty much all I have for now. Thanks for compiling it. I am not sure why it's not working for me.

Comment: @AnAnt: `struct CELL` is not a member of itself. The `next` member is a **pointer** to a `struct CELL`. Structures can contain pointers. This is ordinary C code.

Comment: @user4672 please post a [mcve], meaning the _verbatim_ code you compile and tell us what compiler/IDE/OS/environnment/etc. you use.

Comment: As told, please try to create a [mcve] to show us. And copy-paste the full and complete build output (from the shown code) into the question. And then add comment on the lines where you get the errors.

Comment: @EricPostpischilI yes I realise now !

Comment: As an educated ***guess*** you probably define the `CELL` structure in a header file, but forget to include that header file in the code where you use it.

Comment: Voted to reopen so it can be closed as a duplicate. (There ought to be an option to vote to change the close reason.)

Comment: @EricPostpischil question is open again.

Comment: @Jabberwocky What happened? We reopened it, then closed as a duplicate, then you reopened it ... again? I'm confused.

Answer (score 1):

`table = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(struct HASHCELL));` is a statement (it is an expression statement). Statements cannot be written outside of functions. Outside of functions, you can only have declarations and preprocessing directives. (In the C standard, declarations are separate from statements.)

When the compiler sees `table`, it is expect a declaration, but this is not a declaration because there is no type, like `int table` or `struct Cell table`. The compiler is applying a default type of `int` and warning you about this.

Then, because you had an earlier declaration `struct CELL *table;`, this new “declaration” of `int table` conflicts with the prior declaration, so the compiler warns you about that.

The solution is to write a function, such as the `main` function for your program, and put `table = malloc(SIZE * sizeof(struct HASHCELL));` inside it.

You may also wish to move `struct CELL *table;` inside the function; using variables defined outside of functions is generally bad practice.

Answer (score -3):

Make sure you closed the semicolon at the end of your structure definition.

```
struct CELL {
    char *data;
    struct CELL* next;
};
```

Make sure you include <stdlib.h> standard library where malloc() is defined before you call it.

Cast the return type of malloc to

```
table = (struct CELL*)malloc(100 * sizeof(struct CELL));
```

as malloc always returns `void *` to the allocated memory.

Compile your source code using command line gcc to make sure you don't have any library configuration issues in vs code which may cause the issue.

Comment: C does not require casts of `void *` in assignments; it will automatically be converted to the destination type, and using casts can sometimes obscure errors.

Comment: This is rather a comment than an answer.

Comment: Agreed with the above comments , OP's code already has everything mentioned here, and the cast is implicit . The second part , is probably useful but more of a comment too, and if I might add to it, I'd ask that he compile with all warnings

Comment: In C you really [shouldn't cast the result of `malloc`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/605845/do-i-cast-the-result-of-malloc).

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude brilliant, this is interesting